# switching between two port (Java Socket programming

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I have a university project where i have to create a ftp protocol and i have to switch between two ports (one takes Username/Password , if they are right i switch to another port to send files) but at the point of switching ,the client terminates

Server side (First Port)

```java
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4000);
            System.out.println("Server is booted up and is waiting for clients to connect.");

            while (true) {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("A Client Has Connected");
                Thread client = new clientconnection(clientSocket);
                client.start();
            }
```

Client Side (First Port)

```java
            InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
            Socket clientSocket = new Socket(ip, 4000);
```

Server side (Switching to second port)
P.s it 's inside a thread

```java
                    ServerSocket serverSocket2 = new ServerSocket(4500);
                    clientSocket = serverSocket2.accept();
```

Client Side (Switching to second port)

```java
                        clientSocket = new Socket (ip , 4500);
```

Comment: Could you share more code snippets? It's hard to see what your code is doing from what you provided so far.

Comment: the client will terminate if the `main` thread terminates or if it is running on a separate `thread`, and that `thread` finished it's execution. Check which case is true for the client thread